# Bind a list of some dataframe into 1 dataframe in Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a list of 30 data frames (each of length 53x3) named arr. Now I have to bind all these dataframes into 1 dataframe along row. So the new length of Data frame will be (53x30=1590).
How to do it in Python?
In R, I use rbind function.

Answer (score 0):

For Pyhron:
from the dplyr package use bind_rows:

```
bind_rows(list_of_dataframes, .id = "column_label")
```

Answer (score 0):

Only thing was concat
A = pd.concat(arr)